# MySQL Version 8.0.29, Good index to make this query more efficient

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

```
SELECT ra.id, inv.id
FROM activity ra 
LEFT JOIN inventory inv ON ra.tag_id = inv.tag_id 
WHERE ra.status = :status
```

This is my current query, and sometimes it can be slow, and I am assuming it is due to the join. Is  there any index that would make this query faster?

I believe there is already an index on tag_id and it didn't seem to make it faster.

Comment: Indexes on `activity.Status, activity.tag_id, activity.Id` and `inventory.tag_id, inventory.id`

Answer (score 0):

You never told us on which table the `tag_id` index was.  If you don't already have an index on `tag_id` in the `inventory` table, then add it:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx_tag ON inventory (tag_id);      -- on InnoDB
-- or
CREATE INDEX idx_tag ON inventory (tag_id, id);  -- on MyISAM
```

In addition you may add the following index on the `activity` table:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_status ON activity (status);      -- on InnoDB
-- or
CREATE INDEX idx_status ON activity (status, id);  -- on MyISAM
```